# fancyhdr moves the header on first page after title

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In the code below I have the problem that the 'TOO HIGH' on the first page after the title page is shifted into the header. I want this on the same height as the 'IN THE RIGHT PLACE' on the second page after title page. anyone knows the answer?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{
\scshape
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
asdf
\end{tabular}}
\fancyhead[R]{
\scshape
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
asdf \\ asdf \\ asdf
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
Title

\clearpage
TOO HIGHT -> INSIDE HEADER

\newpage
IN THE RIGHT PLACE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Watch out for unprotected end-of-lines: you get unwanted spaces; add `%` just after `\fancyhead[L]{` to avoid the end-of-line turns into a space: `\fancyhead[L]{%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first page on which a header is placed, `fancyhdr` detects that the parameter `\headheight` is too small:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
Make it at least 40.79997pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Notice the third line of the warning. After changing the `\headheight`, the text body is moved down the page (to make room for the header) on subsequent pages, as alluded to in the last line of the warning. To get consistent page layout, put `\setlength\headheight{40.8pt}` somewhere in the preamble. Since this moves the page body down by about 28.8pt (the difference between the new `\headheight` and the default 12pt), you might (or might not) wish to `\addtolength{\textheight}{-28.8pt}`.